# Three.js scene not reacting while program is running

Tags: javascript, three.js

three.js r114

What happens is that I want to create a playfield field for field.
When a button is pressed, a new playfield shall be created.
That works.

Before the new playfield is created, the old one has to be deleted.
Then the new playfield shall be created with a little delay after every single part of the field.

I tried a lot to make every change directly visible but there are no changes visible while the program is running.

First I try to make the playfield- object3d invisible so I call the method to do so. The field stays visible.

sample code:

```
function make_invisible(){

    playfield.visible = false;
}

make_invisible();
```

The field stays visible.

---

If I return directly after calling that method so my program ends/ class is left, I can see the playfield.

```
function make_invisible(){

   playfield.visible = false;
}

make_invisible();
return;
```

The field goes invisible.

Same with creating the playfield in two simple for- loops ( row/line).
I take a little delay after every part of the playfield that I add to the group which was previously added to the scene so that every second or so a new part of the playfield should show up on screen.
Here I have the same effect, the playfield is shown completely when the script ends but not after the single parts are inserted.

I hope that sounds familiar to some people.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To check an assumption: You need to render() after any changes to a scene for them to update. Threejs won't re-render the scene automatically on changing properties. Do you have a render loop set up with requestAnimationFrame to render() the scene properly?

Comment: Yes, I do. At least the scene is shown and I can rotate the ready- made playfield.
I call the render method after each change.

Comment: What is stored in the variable `playfield` ? You can only apply `.visible` to threejs objects. Assuming you're running a render loop, setting mesh visibility works out of the box with no special requirements, so the error is likely in code you aren't showing us.

Comment: It does work but only when the loop is through and not every cycle of the loop. At the end of the loop the whole playfield get's visible.

Comment: Pardon, playfield is a three.group in which three.meshes are stored. The .visible of these meshes is set to false. After building this playfield I loop through the playfields children, mark them as .visible=true and then make a little pause after each. The meshes do not show up while this loop is running but at the end the whole playfield shows up.
Before doing so, the old playfield is set to .visible=false but stays visible until the new playfield is built and shown.