# Javascript / Three.js - How to pause after adding an object to three.js scene?

Tags: javascript, three.js

what I try to accomplish sounds easy but bothers me for days now.

How may I add Objects to a scene, with a little pause between every adding ?

Within a loop{

I am calling the make_obj- function()

then I call the wait- function().
}

What happens is, that the program does not show the single added objects followed by a pause but puts them all together to the screen when the loop ends after all pauses were made.

I tried to explain it before here

[Three.js scene not reacting while program is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60518120/three-js-scene-not-reacting-while-program-is-running?noredirect=1#comment107086538_60518120)

but it seems to be explained to complicated so I broke it down.

Thanks in advance.

Edit_1:
Yes, I can.
Please be so kind and think of scene and three as objects inserted by another class.
These are standard instantions

```
test = function ( scene, three ){

    this.scene          =   scene;
    this.caller_inst    =   three;


    var that= this;

    var depth_mod=0;

this.start_loop=function(){

    var i;

    for(    i   =   0;
            i   <   10;
            i++
    )
        this.make_objects();
        this.wait(1000);
};


this.wait                       =   function( ms ){

// comment these 2 lines to see effect of "normal" wait loop
    setTimeout(function(){ console.log("Wait!"); }, ms);
    return;

    console.log( "wait start");
    var start   =   new Date    ()
                .   getTime     ();
    var end     =   start;

    while(  end <   start + ms  ){

        end =   new Date    ()
            .   getTime     ();
    }//while
    console.log( "wait ended");
};    


this.make_objects  =   function( count_rows, count_columns ){

var color           =   '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
var sphere_geometry =   new THREE.SphereGeometry(1);
var material1       =   new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: color, specular: 0x555555 });
var sphere_mesh     =   new THREE.Mesh(sphere_geometry, material1);

this.scene.add( sphere_mesh );

    sphere_mesh.position        .   copy            (   that.caller_inst.camera.position );
    sphere_mesh.position.x      =   sphere_mesh.position.x+5+depth_mod;
    sphere_mesh.position.z      =   sphere_mesh.position.z-15 + depth_mod;

    that.caller_inst.renderer   .   render          (   that.caller_inst.scene
                                                    ,   that.caller_inst.camera
                                                    );
    depth_mod                   =   depth_mod-1;

};//function    

};//class
```

I tried a little modification which brings the sam result.

this.start_loop=function(){

```
var i;

for(    i   =   0;
        i   <   10;
        i++
){

setTimeout(function(){ that.make_objects(); }, 1500);
}
```

};

Why does a manual waiting not work like:

```
    var i;

    for(    i   =   0;
            i   <   10;
            i++
    )
        this.object[ i ].visible = true;
        this.wait(1000);
};
```

?

Comment: Assuming the `wait` function is just some loop, then you are blocking the thread. You need to wait in an asynchronous way, likely using `setTimeout`.

Comment: Hi Jake,
thanks for taking time.

I tried
var start   =   new Date    ()
                .   getTime     ();
    var end     =   start;
    
    while(  end <   start + ms  ){
    
        end =   new Date    ()
            .   getTime     ();
    }

and I tried

setTimeout(function(){ console.log("Wait!"); }, ms);

Which both behaves similar.

Comment: They shouldn't be behaving similar, but I cannot provide an answer unless you add some more details. Do you have any code to share?

Comment: @Paul Can you add the code to your question? It's impossible to know what's going wrong without seeing what you're trying. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for help formatting the code in your question.

Comment: In the end it is........





SETINTERVAL



For that reason Jake Holzingers comment might be the first who got it right.

Thanks to all for your time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

With setTimeout function.

Make a function that adds an object. Then just call that via setTimeout. For multiple additions, you can just add another setTimeout call at the end of your object adding function.

```
function sayHi() {
  alert('Hello');
}

setTimeout(sayHi, 1000);
```

This page seems to have nice examples: https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do something in a loop with a pause. The modern es6 way is to use [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function doThingsOverTime() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    console.log(i);    // add object here
    await wait(1000);  // wait 1 second
  }
}

doThingsOverTime();
```

example:

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r113/build/three.module.js';

const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 40;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 50;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 16;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(-1, 2, 4);
    scene.add(light);
  }

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  function makeInstance(geometry, color, x) {
    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color});

    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

    cube.position.x = x;

    return cube;
  }

  const cubes = [];

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;  // convert time to seconds

    cubes.forEach((cube, ndx) => {
      const speed = 1 + ndx * .1;
      const rot = time * speed;
      cube.rotation.x = rot;
      cube.rotation.y = rot;
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  const numCubes = 11;
  for (let i = 0; i < numCubes; ++i) {
    const u = i / (numCubes - 1);
    const x = (u * 2 - 1) * 10;
    cubes.push(makeInstance(geometry, `hsl(${u * 360},100%,70%)`, x));
    await wait(1000);
  }   
}

main();
</script>
```